# Pandas vs. Numpy Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, dataframe

Look at these few lines of code:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2[1:] = df[1:]/df[:-1].values -1
df2.ix[0, :] = 0
```

Our instructor said we need to use the **.values** attribute to access the underlying numpy array, otherwise, our code wouldn't work.

I understand that a pandas DataFrame does have an underlying representation as a numpy array, but I didn't understand why we cannot operate directly on the pandas DataFrame using just slicing.

May you elucidate me about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pandas focuses on tabular data structures and when doing the operations (addition, subtraction etc.) it looks at the labels - not positions.

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=list('abcde'), columns=list('xyz'))
```

Here, `df[1:]` is:

```
df[1:]
Out: 
          x         y         z
b  1.003035  0.172960  1.160033
c  0.117608 -1.114294 -0.557413
d -1.312315  1.171520 -1.034012
e -0.380719 -0.422896  1.073535
```

And `df[:-1]` is:

```
df[:-1]
Out: 
          x         y         z
a  1.367916  1.087607 -0.625777
b  1.003035  0.172960  1.160033
c  0.117608 -1.114294 -0.557413
d -1.312315  1.171520 -1.034012
```

If you do `df[1:] / df[:-1]` it will divide row `b`'s by row `b`'s, row `c`'s by row `c`'s and row `d`'s by row `d`'s. For row `a` and `e`, it will not be able to find corresponding rows in the other DataFrame (either in the first one or in the second one) so it will return `nan`:

```
df[1:] / df[:-1]
Out: 
     x    y    z
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  1.0  1.0  1.0
c  1.0  1.0  1.0
d  1.0  1.0  1.0
e  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you just want to do element-wise division ignoring the labels, accessing the underlying numpy array by `.values` for one of the frames is a way of telling pandas to ignore labels. Since numpy arrays don't have labels, pandas will just do element-wise operations:

```
df[1:]/df[:-1].values
Out: 
           x         y         z
b   0.733258  0.159028 -1.853749
c   0.117252 -6.442482 -0.480515
d -11.158359 -1.051357  1.855018
e   0.290112 -0.360981 -1.038223
```

Comment: Now, I understand that the final result would have been the same, but I wonder if it would have been more formally correct to use a numpy array for the numerator, too..

Comment: In that case, the whole operation will be in numpy so it will return an array without labels. Note that in the final output (`df[1:]/df[:-1].values`) the result is a DataFrame. So it will be based on your needs.