# Using numpy.ndarray vs. Pandas Dataframe in sklearn's .fit() method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm using a Logistic Regression model on my data. From what I understand (e.g. from here: [Pandas vs. Numpy Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832735/pandas-vs-numpy-dataframes)), it's better to use numpy.ndarray with sklearn than to use Pandas Dataframes. This can be done by using the .values attribute on the dataframe. I have done this, but get the ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames. 
Clearly, I am doing something wrong with my code. Any insights are much appreciated.

Funnily enough, my code works when I don't use .values, and just use X as a DataFrame and y as a Pandas Series.

```
# We will train our classifier with the following features:
# Numeric features to be scaled: LIMIT_BAL, AGE, PAY_X, BIL_AMTX, and PAY_AMTX
# Categorical features: SEX, EDUCATION, MARRIAGE

# We create the preprocessing pipelines for both numeric and categorical data
numeric_features = ['LIMIT_BAL', 'AGE', 'PAY_1', 'PAY_2', 'PAY_3', 'PAY_4', 'PAY_5', 'PAY_6', 
                 'BILL_AMT1', 'BILL_AMT2', 'BILL_AMT3', 'BILL_AMT4', 'BILL_AMT5', 'BILL_AMT6', 
                 'PAY_AMT1', 'PAY_AMT2', 'PAY_AMT3', 'PAY_AMT4', 'PAY_AMT5', 'PAY_AMT6']

data['PAY_1'] = data.PAY_1.astype('float64')
data['PAY_2'] = data.PAY_2.astype('float64')
data['PAY_3'] = data.PAY_3.astype('float64')
data['PAY_4'] = data.PAY_4.astype('float64')
data['PAY_5'] = data.PAY_5.astype('float64')
data['PAY_6'] = data.PAY_6.astype('float64')
data['AGE'] = data.AGE.astype('float64')


numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
('scaler', MinMaxScaler())
])

categorical_features = ['SEX', 'EDUCATION', 'MARRIAGE']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
('onehot', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
    ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
    ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)
])

y = data['default'].values
X = data.drop('default', axis=1).values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=10, stratify=y)

# Append classifier to preprocessing pipeline.
# Now we have a full prediction pipeline.
lr = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                 ('classifier', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'))])

param_grid_lr = {
'classifier__C': np.logspace(-5, 8, 15)
}

lr_cv = GridSearchCV(lr, param_grid_lr, cv=10, iid=False)

lr_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames

Comment: added the code for the preprocessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ColumnTransformer` as if you had a dataframe, but you don't have one...

> **column(s)** : string or int, array-like of string or int, slice, boolean mask array or callable
>
> Indexes the data on its second axis. Integers are interpreted as positional columns, **while strings can reference DataFrame columns by name**. A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer. A callable is passed the input data X and can return any of the above.

If you pass strings for the columns, you need to pass a dataframe. If you want to use a numpy array, then first the transtyping may not be required and you need to specify integers and not strings as index.

Comment: thank you, Matthieu. Is there any benefit to using a numpy array over a pandas dataframe? I can't see that there would be, I'm just wondering.

Comment: Depends on the algorithms after, a contiguous array might be better for some models.